# tvOS - Replacing UISlider

Tags: uislider, tvos, siri-remote

I am extending an iOS app for tvOS.

On iOS app I have a lot of sliders (two-sided slider to choose a range for years eg. 1950-2010. or values from 0.1 to 10.0).

I was wondering how I am supposed to replace this functionality on tvOS.
My initial thought was to override the volume buttons of Siri remote and change the values but I don't believe that `Apple` would allow that.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to implement 2 buttons (arrow icons). One for increasing and one for decreasing the year value.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `UIProgressView` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. When the user swipes left or right, you can change the `progress` of the `UIProgressView` accordingly.